# How to organise pytest cases using pytest-describe plugin

Tags: pytest

Does anyone has examples about how to run pytest using describe plugin. I am looking to arrange my pytests using arbitrary nested blocks. This plug in seems to do that but I dont see any examples. Can someone help?

Abhijeet

Answer (score 0):

[describe blocks come from rspec](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/basic-structure-describe-it), and this answer is informed by how it's done in rspec.

A common pattern when writing tests using rspec is to organize by class and then by method. Test names should describe the context and expected behavior.

```
def describe_cat():
  def describe_eat():
    def it_randomly_wont_eat():
    def with_tuna_it_will_always_eat():
```

If you're writing functions, do a describe block per function.

```
def describe_something():
  def with_no_arguments_it_uses_defaults():
  def it_validates_the_name():
```

This pattern both helps organize the code, avoiding a giant monolith file. And it ensures you're writing unit tests; each test tests one thing.